# SharePoint solution deployment issue

Tags: solution-deployment

I am trying to deploy a WSP solution in SP2010 using a PowerShell script and it's showing the status in CA as "Deploying" for a long time. I have tried:

1. `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs`
2. `stsadm -o enumdeployments`
3. `Remove-SPSolution -ID -force`  (Finally to remove the solution )
4. Restarted SharePoint 2010 Timer Job in services.msc

But I'm still facing the same problem once I deploy it again. Any Help

Comment: If you can inlcude a copy of your powershell deployment script, that might be useful too.

Comment: I am have the same problem when deploying a wsp in SP2010.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything in the ULS logs? I have seen the deployment hang when the services don't have the correct access to a box, or the services aren't running (ie: setup account must be local admin on all boxes in the farm, and the timer service must be running), but it'll typically come back after a period of attempts and tell you it failed.

Without more information, it's difficult to provide any guidance.

Comment: SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'ServerName' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Login failed for user 'domainname\servername'.

Comment: If you're getting an access error like that I'm assuming you're running the deployment under your personal credentials, and not the setup account. Log on to the box using the setup/install account (which will have the correct permissions), and retry the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Timer job is running on **ALL** servers in the farm, not merely the server you are running the commands on.  Beyond that, make sure that the account that you are logged in on has sufficient permissions on the farm.

Comment: I just have one server running like wfe/app.

Comment: In that case, set your Diagnostic logging to Verbose/Verbose, rerun the deployment, giving it about 5 minutes to run, then look at the latest logs in 14/LOGS for any errors or other unexpected results.  ULS Viewer (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) helps considerably with this task!

Comment: ULS Viewer shows an Error : SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'ServerName' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. Login failed for user 'domainname\servername'.

Comment: I assume you are running this as your user account so the quickest way to get around it is to run the SharePoint Command Console as the Farm account (Shift-right click on the link and select Run As User) and attempt the deployment under that account.  If that works, then you will need to do some troubleshooting to determine exactly where the permissions for your user account are falling short as you really don't want to make it a habit of logging in under the farm account.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I had fixed this issue in main server (using powershell commands) but still needs to fix it in dev server.